# Installing Postgis on Raspberry Pi to PostgreSql 9.6

Tags: raspbian-jessie, arm

I'm trying to install Postgis 2.3 on Pi running Jessie.
I have tried using apt-get but this installs the Postgis for Postgres 9.4.
And hence I cannot use it on the 9.6.

So I've tried to compile from code using [this](http://postgis.net/docs/postgis_installation.html#install_requirements) source.
But I end up with

```
> checking for pg_config... /usr/bin/pg_config You need to install
> postgresql-server-dev-X.Y for building a server-side extension or
> libpq-dev for building a client-side application. configure: error:
> the PGXS Makefile  cannot be found. Please install the PostgreSQL
> server development packages and re-run configure.
```

after I run `./configure`

Has anyone tried to find out how one can go on achieving this.
I've also tried with a different .config file but it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Have you tried to install the missing libs the script is complaining about?

Comment: Yes I have. But when I try installing the libs it says I have to remove some existing libs. And when I did that and installed this one my psql stops working since it was using the previous libs.

Answer (score 2):

Use these following commands, this will solve the error:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql postgis
```

and last:

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

[Referring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28253681/you-need-to-install-postgresql-server-dev-x-y-for-building-a-server-side-extensi)

Comment: The problem with this type of installation is it will target x64 type of architecture which would not work on a pi.

Comment: Please visit this [link](http://raspberrypg.org/2015/06/step-5-update-installing-postgresql-on-my-raspberry-pi-1-and-2/)